# How to view the data stored on transaction log?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm using hyperledger fabric 2.0. I have successfully ran chaincodes on the fabric network and my data is storing on the couch db. I'm viewing the data stored on the couch [DB using](http://%20http://localhost:5984/_utils/#/_all_dbs)

But I want to prove to my faculty that the data is being stored on the transaction log too. Is there any way to view the data that is stored on the transaction log?

Comment: If you are looking for some graphical type representation then setup `Hyperledger-explorer`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you basically want to retrieve the ledger data while you're already able to access the world state (couch-db).

One way could be, depending upon what SDK you're using, you can use an instance of 'Channel' and run queries against the ledger data.

Following are the [methods available in NodeSDK](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/Channel.html) which could help you to run queries against your ledger:

- queryBlock
- queryBlockByHash
- queryBlockByTxID
- queryTransaction